# How to copy a country map so it can be used by VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have downloaded a countries powerpoint file that can be found here: http://www.pptpop.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/PPTPOP.COM_Editable-maps+pins.pptx. This gives me a great map,

However I would the map now as picture so I can use in another presentation. Because I have a large amound of presentations where I need a map of Europe with one country highlighted Im looking to save the worldmap in a way so I can call it with a macro.

If I click on one country I can edit the points. My question is whether you think there is a way to copy the country by the following exercise:

- Select one country
- Use VBA to outline the coordinates of the points
- Use VBA to connect the lines between te dots

This all so I can reproduce the pictures. Also happy to hear if there is another way.

Comment: I could not open the file, it is corrupted

Comment: I had a look at the maps in that presentation and they are made up of grouped shapes. As each country is a shape all you need to do is select the shape for the country you want to highlight and set the line colour for that shape.